# How to select words with apostrophe using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to separate a string into a list, but I need to have the string contain words that are joined by apostrophes. For example :

```
String="My name is Melvin_JESUS, Guatemala, Dean'Olvier, 501soy...@ 1231 !"
```

should give me a result as:

```
['my', 'name', 'is', 'melvin', 'jesus', 'guatemala', '"dean'oliver"', 'soy']
```

i have tried the following regular expression:

```
my_patern= r"(?:^|(?<=\s)|-)[A-Za-z'\.]+(?=\s|\t|$|\b)"
```

but doesn't give me the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<![^\W\d_])[^\W\d_]+(?:['.][^\W\d_]+)*(?![^\W\d_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IVWOu3/1)

**Details**

- `(?<![^\W\d_])` - no letter right before the match is allowed
- `[^\W\d_]+` - 1 or more letters
- `(?:['.][^\W\d_]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of `'` or `.` and then 1+ letters
- `(?![^\W\d_])` - no letter right after the match is allowed.

In Python, use

```
re.findall(r'(?<![^\W\d_])[^\W\d_]+(?:['.][^\W\d_]+)*(?![^\W\d_])', text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...this explation helps me a lot